# access ggplot2 base layers from within custom function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to get my head around writing custom code for ggplot2.

I have following code below which implements a dummy custom color scale.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

someData <- data.frame(x = 1:100 + runif(n = 100, min = -10, max = 10), y = 1:100 + runif(n = 100, min = -10, max = 10), label1 = sample(letters[1:10], size = 100, replace = T), label2 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = T)) %>%
    mutate(label2 = as.factor(label2))

scale_color_shapely <- function(...) {
    discrete_scale("color", scale_name = "blaaa", palette = scales::hue_pal(), ...)
}

plot <- ggplot(data = someData, aes(x = x, y = y, color = label1, shape = label2)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_shapely(name = "myDummyColorScale")
```

[image]

To expand this function, I'd like to acces information contained in already-existing layers of the ggplot2 object (such as the number of distinct values in `label1` of , for example).

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scale object doesn't have full access to the data in the plot object, but it has access to the unique values from the variable mapped to it via `labels` and the range via `breaks`. For example, to access and print the number of unique values in your scale, you could change your scale function to:

```r
scale_color_shapely <- function(...) {
  discrete_scale("color", scale_name = "blaaa", 
                 palette = scales::hue_pal(), 
                 labels = function(x) { print(length(x)); x}, ...)
}
```

Resulting in:

```r
ggplot(data = someData, aes(x = x, y = y, color = label1, shape = label2)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_shapely(name = "myDummyColorScale")
```

[image]

```
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>